# How do I install a pgfkeys .unknown handler for a whole keys subtree?

Tags: pgfkeys

I'm trying to define a subtree of my tree of `pgfkeys` keys such that any key, at any path under that subtree, will be assignable without having to previously define the key.

In other words, I would like any path under `/mykeys/` to be assignable without a previous definition, like:

```
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/key=hello} % ok
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/nested/key=hello} % ok
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/any/arbitrarily/nested/key=hello} % still ok
```

The original idea was to install an `.unknown` handler to silently initialize the key with the given value and go on. However, it seems this approach only works for the first level of the tree, *i.e.* for the first line of the above example. I've also tried using the `.unknown` handler to install an `.unknown` handler inside the unknown key itself, but the handler seems to be not called when the key is used as part of a path.

To be clear: I don't know in advance the key paths that will be used: I need it to work for any arbitrary path inside `/mykeys`.

The code I tried is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand\unknown[1]{%
  \def\@key{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{\@key}{#1}%
  \pgfkeys{\@key/.unknown/.code = {\unknown{#1}}}
}

\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/.unknown/.code = {\unknown{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/key=hello}
Value: \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/key}

\pgfkeys{/mykeys/nested/key=hello}
Value: \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/nested/key}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the first invocation of `\pgfkeys` works, and `\pgfkeysvalueof` returns the correct value, while the second doesn't.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised because I thought that defining your keys as:

```
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.is family, /mykeys, 
    .unknown/.code = {
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#‌​1}
    }
}
```

would do what you want, but the unknown handler is not applying recursively. It seems that one way out is to override the generic `.unknown` handler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.is family, /mykeys}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown/.code = {
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/key=hello}
Value: \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/key}

\pgfkeys{/mykeys/nested/key=hello}
Value: \pgfkeysvalueof{/mykeys/nested/key}

\end{document}
```

This produces the wanted output:

[image]

Of course, now *every* unknown key will be set this way, which may have unwanted side effects

Comment: Interesting! Can’t one save the old unknown handler and call it when `\pgfkeyscurrentpath` does not start with `/mykeys`?

Comment: @gigabytes Probably. I thought about this but it seems painful to test if `\pgfkeyscurrentpath` starts with `/mykeys`. Quite likely, `pgfkeys` provides a mechanism for doing this but I don't know it. I was hoping that one of the pgf experts on TeX.SX would provide a "better" solution:)

Comment: I think one has to resort to generic string manipulation techniques.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution to this same problem without much luck as well.

This seems to work (not very thoroughly tested, and if someone has a better solution, I'd love to see it)

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown/.code=
  {%
    \IfBeginWith{\pgfkeyscurrentkey}{/myprefix}{%
      \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}%
    }{%
      {Unknown key ‘\pgfkeyscurrentkey’.}%
    }%
  }%
}%
```